# Solution for Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet issue in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a solution for Got a packet bigger than `max_allowed_packet` issue in Rails
while saving the huge data in longblob datatype column?

I don't want to increase the size of `max_allowed_packet` variables.

Comment: I'm presuming you're using MySQL?

Comment: Are you hitting the max allowed packet size with the whole statement of several fields being inserted at once on a row or just one field in one row?

Comment: just fire the Model.updateAttribute(:report_data,data) query for longblob filed 'data' (for mysql database)

Comment: @chuck-d (via [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6415345)): Please stop saying "Formatted as per SO guidelines".  There isn't actually any such guideline, and it somewhat bothers me.  Say "Put code in code formatting", as that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got a packet bigger than the `max_allowed_packet` then, short of sending less data, I think you might have to increase the size of `max_allowed_packet`.

Presuming that you're using MySQL, you could try executing these SQL statements (as opposed to editing your `my.cnf` file to set the value of `max_allowed_packet`):

```
set global max_allowed_packet = 1000*1024*1024;
set global net_buffer_length = 1000000;
```

You can then check it worked by running this:

```
select @@max_allowed_packet;
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply but as i mentioned that i don't want to increase the size or change in my.cnf file.
Is there any other solution for this issue?